# Modifying Unique Pairing to Existing Table

Tags: mysql

Hello I have am existing table which is as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE customer (
id          INT NOT NULL auto_increment,
name        VARCHAR(64),
location    VARCHAR(64),
PRIMARY KEY (id),
UNIQUE (name, location)
);
```

I am trying to add a phone number to the customer record which is also a unique value by doing the following:

```
ALTER TABLE customer ADD phone VARCHAR(16) NOT NULL;
ALTER TABLE ADD UNIQUE (name, location, phone);
```

When I try this sql is complaining about my syntax on the table update. Is there a way to add a unique constraint to an existing unique key pair?

Comment: Please add the syntax error you mentioned to the question.

Comment: You probably need to `DROP INDEX` first and then re-create it with `ALTER TABLE ADD UNIQUE`, so better to give it a name in the first place: `ALTER TABLE ADD UNIQUE 
 IX_unq (name, location); DROP INDEX IX_unq; ALTER TABLE ADD UNIQUE 
 IX_unq (name, location, phone);`